# ID Serial não atribuindo ao id do model

Tags: php, postgresql, mvc, yii2

Estou fazendo um site que recebe por uma Webservice, os dados de um dvd(de um site de outro colega), e cria uma oferta com as informações dele. Creio que eu esteja tendo problema com a estruturação MVC e não com o framework em si.

```
public function uploadImagem($base64){
    $nomeImagem = $this->ofe_id;

    $this->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'file');

    if($this->file){
        $this->file->saveAs('imagens/'.$nomeImagem.$this->file->extension);
        $this->ofe_imagem = ('imagens/'.$nomeImagem.$this->file->extension);
    }else{
        file_put_contents('imagens/'.$nomeImagem, base64_decode($base64));
        $this->ofe_imagem = ('imagens/'.$nomeImagem);
        $this->save();
    }

}
```

Nessa função, eu crio uma imagem no meu banco baseada no Base64 que recebo da webservice dele, e nomeio ela com o ID da oferta criada.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model          = new Oferta();
    $categorias     = \app\models\Categoria::find()->all();
    $tipos          = \app\models\TipoOferta::find()->all();
    $subcategorias  = \app\models\Subcategoria::find()->all();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $conteudoDaImagem = Yii::$app->request->post('imagem');


        $model->ofe_emp_id      = Yii::$app->user->identity->usu_emp_id;
        $model->ofe_cliques     = 0;
        $model->ofe_titulo      = $_POST['ofe_titulo'];
        $model->ofe_sub_id      = $_POST['subcategoria'];
        $model->ofe_tipo_id     = $_POST['ofe_tipo_id'];
        $model->ofe_redir       = $_POST['ofe_redir'];

        if ($model->uploadImagem($conteudoDaImagem) || $conteudoDaImagem){
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ofe_id]);
        }else{
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'categorias' => $categorias,
        'tipos' => $tipos,
        'subcategorias' => $subcategorias,
    ]);

}
```

Nessa action no controller de Oferta, eu atribuo ao modelo, os valores que recebo do formulário e salvo, novamente.

Minha coluna Oferta:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu problema tem sido o seguinte:
Sempre que eu tento criar uma nova oferta, o ofe_id que seria o ID da oferta, fica em branco, mesmo que no banco, a coluna esta como tipo Serial. Isso acaba afetando a nomenclatura da imagem, assim como não permite de fato criar uma oferta, pois a coluna Ofe_id deve ser preenchida.

Acho que estou tendo problemas com a estruturação MVC e não com o Yii2 em si, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço, desde já.

Comment: Olá Victor, tudo bom? Altere as suas imagens para o seu código, pois aqui no fórum utilizamos o seu próprio código para te ajudar. Procure ler as políticas do site para entender melhor o funcionamento das publicações. Abraço.

Comment: Olá Pedro, corrigido, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Por nada cara, tmj!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu model->save() tem que vir antes de $model->uploadImagem
Por que o $id ainda não existe enquanto essa model não for salva no banco de dados.
Seu código reorganizado para funcionar:

```
    $model->ofe_emp_id      = Yii::$app->user->identity->usu_emp_id;
    $model->ofe_cliques     = 0;
    $model->ofe_titulo      = $_POST['ofe_titulo'];
    $model->ofe_sub_id      = $_POST['subcategoria'];
    $model->ofe_tipo_id     = $_POST['ofe_tipo_id'];
    $model->ofe_redir       = $_POST['ofe_redir'];
    $model->save();

    $conteudoDaImagem = Yii::$app->request->post('imagem');
    if ($model->uploadImagem($conteudoDaImagem) || $conteudoDaImagem){
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ofe_id]);
    }else{
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Comment: Modifiquei aqui e deu certo, obg pela ajuda

Comment: Por nada. Da um voto ai pra resposta se puder.